# I can see the emitted and received messages in the console tab but not the network tab

Tags: networking, socket.io-client

So basically I made this simple client code

```
const socket = io('wss://rapidbus-socketio-avl.prasarana.com.my');

socket.on('connect', () => {
  console.log("connected")
  socket.emit("onFts-reload",{"sid":"aqfb7rbspkdc36v0vfudmlsebdqq1svg","uid":"","provider":"RKL","route":"U1510"});
});

// handle the event sent with socket.emit()
socket.on("onFts-client",data => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And it logs connected..
In  the console tab here Is what shows

```
socket.io-client:url parse wss://rapidbus-socketio-avl.prasarana.com.my +0ms
browser.js:136 socket.io-client new io instance for wss://rapidbus-socketio-avl.prasarana.com.my +0ms
browser.js:136 socket.io-client:manager readyState closed +0ms
browser.js:136 socket.io-client:manager opening wss://rapidbus-socketio-avl.prasarana.com.my +0ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:socket creating transport "polling" +0ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling polling +0ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +0ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open GET: https://rapidbus-socketio-avl.prasarana.com.my/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OeI20ej +2ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +1ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:socket setting transport polling +7ms
browser.js:136 socket.io-client:manager connect attempt will timeout after 20000 +11ms
browser.js:136 socket.io-client:manager readyState opening +1ms
rapidBus.html:40 Live reload enabled.
favicon.ico:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
rapidBus.html:1 A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://rapidbus-socketio-avl.prasarana.com.my/ was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling polling got data ArrayBuffer(118) +6s
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "open", data "{"sid":"3a48b549-5e4e-4fbf-a0b1-86393bd20c17","upgrades":["websocket"],"pingInterval":25000,"pingTimeout":60000}" +6s
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:socket socket open +1ms
browser.js:136 socket.io-client:manager open +6s
browser.js:136 socket.io-client:manager cleanup +1ms
browser.js:136 socket.io-client:socket transport is open - connecting +0ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:socket starting upgrade probes +2ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:socket probing transport "websocket" +1ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:socket creating transport "websocket" +0ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling polling +13ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +6s
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open GET: https://rapidbus-socketio-avl.prasarana.com.my/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OeI224R&sid=3a48b549-5e4e-4fbf-a0b1-86393bd20c17 +1ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +0ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling polling got data ArrayBuffer(5) +1s
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "message", data "0" +1s
browser.js:136 socket.io-parser decoded 0 as {"type":0,"nsp":"/"} +0ms
rapidBus.js:4 connected
browser.js:136 socket.io-client:manager writing packet {"type":2,"data":["onFts-reload",{"sid":"aqfb7rbspkdc36v0vfudmlsebdqq1svg","uid":"","provider":"RKL","route":"U1510"}],"options":{"compress":true},"nsp":"/"} +1s
browser.js:136 socket.io-parser encoding packet {"type":2,"data":["onFts-reload",{"sid":"aqfb7rbspkdc36v0vfudmlsebdqq1svg","uid":"","provider":"RKL","route":"U1510"}],"options":{"compress":true},"nsp":"/"} +13ms
browser.js:136 socket.io-parser encoded {"type":2,"data":["onFts-reload",{"sid":"aqfb7rbspkdc36v0vfudmlsebdqq1svg","uid":"","provider":"RKL","route":"U1510"}],"options":{"compress":true},"nsp":"/"} as 2["onFts-reload",{"sid":"aqfb7rbspkdc36v0vfudmlsebdqq1svg","uid":"","provider":"RKL","route":"U1510"}] +3ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:socket flushing 1 packets in socket +22ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open POST: https://rapidbus-socketio-avl.prasarana.com.my/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OeI22O7&sid=3a48b549-5e4e-4fbf-a0b1-86393bd20c17 +1s
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data 103:42["onFts-reload",{"sid":"aqfb7rbspkdc36v0vfudmlsebdqq1svg","uid":"","provider":"RKL","route":"U1510"}] +17ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling polling +62ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr poll +17ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr open GET: https://rapidbus-socketio-avl.prasarana.com.my/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=OeI22Of&sid=3a48b549-5e4e-4fbf-a0b1-86393bd20c17 +1ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling-xhr xhr data null +1ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:polling polling got data ArrayBuffer(534) +703ms
browser.js:136 engine.io-client:socket socket receive: type "message", data "2["onFts-client","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"]" +743ms
browser.js:136 socket.io-parser decoded 2["onFts-client","H4sIAAAAAAAAAMXTT0vDMBQA8K8iOW/jvZcmTXr0JNODCFNBpHRdGMHSljYdiPjdTTrnplvrQWTHvD/Jy4/k6Y2tXNqY3NiNWbGEERCfgpoSXKBMUCeg2CTUrOt2MF1kzrpuZVjCZxgTlz5UlevPGALOpEbtt7GN3wPIt7S1CefxeAYTlpXrIhQKFVZN1Tm/YgsUCL502bVpWfnA7XyOSkc+5Bpbb2NhIFAEKAj7BtpX5VntMlumNlwMATBCCbvuxmzSF1uGFISg8fOWJm1d5jp/U/RT5blpW7u0hXWvfcRP0rqq7jcsu6KYsLqpNnZlwrXurm/Y++RXz0iOevbpb55SED/hKenLE/eeRAeefFTzYfEoFPEBTQF9A+6rfmqCkqjOqgncv59hzZA+0oyEFic0lTj1OuEAE8Yx7y+F1AOY/szt09xXHWFKpem8mJREMIJJCdc/MElIOIEp4r9aXkniA99cAu0sd1VHljyW+n8tn
```

[image: While the network tab shows this]

How can I make the emitted and received data show in the network (WS) tab on my browser. Thanks for the future help I appreciate it